# Is it possible to create a standalone Windows Silverlight Embedded Application for CE 6.0 R3?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce

We are investigating using Silverlight as our UI creator.  We can get a subproject running from the Platform builder but would like to pull this code to a standalone VS project.  I have an SDK built from Platform builder with Silverlight added in.  Currently I am getting unresolved external symbol errors in the project build against this SDK.

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol GetXRApplicationInstance referenced in function WinMain   SilverlightTestApp.obj  SilverlightTestApp

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol XamlRuntimeInitialize referenced in function WinMain  SilverlightTestApp.obj  SilverlightTestApp

The library files where XamlRuntime.lib and uuid.lib are located have been included.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I feel like I am running up against a brick wall currently.

Edit:
The Silverlight runtime that comes with CE6R3 only supports Silverlight 2 functionality. That means you can use either Blend 2 or Blend 3 but you will have to create a Silverlight 2 project. You can use either VS2005 or VS2008 to create your application as long as you use the correct SDK and target the right device. HOWEVER, you will not be able to use WEST since these tools specifically target the Silverlight runtime that comes with CE7  (essentially Silverlight 3). Also you can NOT use the VS2008 project template for silverlight for embedded that installs with WEST and CE7. The code that this template generates is not compatible with CE6R3.

So I am not able to use the page below because it is based off of WEST and we are using the CE 6.0R3

Comment: @HiTechMagic Ashley is speaking about Silverlight for Windows Embedded Compact, which is a native runtime and not a .net one, Microsoft has two Silverlight poducts, the only thing in common being Expression Blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial and it should work, probably you haven't converted well the Blend project into a Visual Studio one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightforwindowsembedded/archive/2010/07/19/first-silverlight-for-windows-embedded-application.aspx

Comment: I am using Expression Blend 2 with CE 6.0 R3.  I don't think that Blend 3 is compatible with CE 6.0 R3.  But I will try the steps in the tutorial

Comment: Yes, you are right Blend 2 is for WinCE 6.0 R3, but the steps should be the same.

Comment: The code that this template generates is not compatible with CE6R3.

Comment: Hmmm, well I think there is an utility called XML2CPP.exe that was making this conversion.

Comment: @Ashley A tutorial here for XML2CPP: http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/11/11/xaml2cpp.aspx

Comment: Thank you.. I have used this and gotten it to work in the platform builder we are trying to pull it out into a project that will run on top (our platform takes about 30 minutes to recompile with every change).   I am not sure that it is possible from all of the searching I have done so far.

Comment: For me it looks like you're having a link problem. In your makefile you should have something like this: TARGETLIBS= \
    $(_PROJECTROOT)\cesysgen\sdk\lib\$(_CPUINDPATH)\coredll.lib \
    $(_PROJECTROOT)\cesysgen\sdk\lib\$(_CPUINDPATH)\xamlruntime.lib \
    
INCLUDES= \
$(_WINCEROOT)\public\common\sdk\inc; \
$(_WINCEROOT)\public\common\oak\inc; \